# How to transform a Kentico Email Template without sending it?

Tags: kentico

My Kentico server is unable to send e-mails, so I have to transform my e-mail using MacroResolver, but send it using some other way.

```
var clients = new List<Client>();

var macroResolver = MacroResolver.GetInstance();
macroResolver.AddDynamicParameter("clients", clients);

var emailMessage = new EmailMessage { 
    From = "someone@somewhere.com", 
    Recipients = "otherone@somewhere.com", 
    Subject = "Whatever" 
};

var template = EmailTemplateProvider.GetEmailTemplate(templateName, siteName);

EmailSender.SendEmailWithTemplateText(siteName, emailMessage, template, macroResolver, true);
```

In other words, I would like to use Kentico just as a Template Engine. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `SendEmailWithTemplateText` method basically does is it fills empty fields of message by its equivalent from a template and resolve macro values in it. If you are only after message body, then you can create the email message by:

```
emailMessage.Body = macroResolver.ResolveMacros(emailMessage.Body);
emailMessage.PlainTextBody = macroResolver.ResolveMacros(emailMessage.PlainTextBody);
```

For most scenarios it's also better to tell the resolver to encode resolved values. You can do it by: `resolver.EncodeResolvedValues = true;`

Also you are passing whole 'clients' collection to the resolver. You'll probably need to take it one by one and generate emails in a loop.